# How does compound literals work in this code?

Tags: c, gcc, c99, compound-literals

I have the following code in which I wrote two functions. Both are meant to produce the same output. But the function `g()` which has loop produces a different output from what I had expected as shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct S { int i; };

void f(void)
{
    struct S *p;

    int i = 0;

    p = &((struct S) {i});
    printf("%p\n", p);

    i++;

    p = &((struct S) {i});
    printf("%p\n", p);
}

void g(void)
{
    struct S *p;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        p = &((struct S) {i});
        printf("%p\n", p);
    }
}

int main()
{   
    printf("Calling function f()\n");
    f();

    printf("\nCalling function g()\n");
    g();
}
```

Output:

```
Calling function f()
0023ff20
0023ff24

Calling function g()
0023ff24
0023ff24
```

How come the address of `p` is same in case of `g()` when it was called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I don't know exactly what are you trying to accomplish, but what happens here is:

- the `(struct S){i}` notation in C99 will create new data structure on stack
- this data structure is automaticaly destroyed at the end of the scope in which it was created

So in `f()` function you actually make TWO distinct structures in the scope of the whole function (even if you assign their addresses to the same pointer) - hence two different addresses.

```
void f(void)
{
    struct S *p;

    int i = 0;

    p = &((struct S) {i}); // <- first data structure, let's call it A
    printf("%p\n", p);     // <- address of the structure A printed

    i++;

    p = &((struct S) {i}); // <- second data structure, let's call it B
    printf("%p\n", p);     // <- address of the structure B printed
}                          // <- both A and B destroyed
```

But in `g()` function the `p` is created and destroyed in the inner block of the `for` block, and so it happens that p is allocated over and over again in the same position on stack, giving always the same address.

```
void g(void)
{
    struct S *p;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        p = &((struct S) {i}); // <- data structure A created
        printf("%p\n", p);     // <- data structure A's address printed
    }                          // <- data structure A destroyed
}
```

Comment: I tried by enclosing `f()` in two local scopes for each `struct` but it didn't change the result, I guess it's weird.

Comment: Thanks. I got `&((struct S) {i})` confused with being a static storage object somehow. I didn't see what was going on.

Answer (score 2):

You should check assembly code to be sure but I guess that, since `p` is assigned locally in a loop scope with the address of an automatic allocated variable (which is allocated on the stack), it just reuses the same space on the stack.

In `f()` it doesn't do it because both structs coexist in the same scope while in `g()` compiler is sure that at the end of the first iteration you won't be able to use `&((struct S) {0})`.

Just tried for curiosity with `-O2` on gcc4.2 to see if anything changes:

```
Calling function f()
0x7fff5fbff388
0x7fff5fbff380

Calling function g()
0x7fff5fbff390
0x7fff5fbff390
```

Comment: Just curious - what's the change you've observed with `-O2`? All I see is the same output as before - `f` giving two different addresses, `g` giving two same addresses..